# Multiple Twitter applications with omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, omniauth-twitter

I've configured devise + omniauth as documented on omniauth wiki: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Setup-Phase

My initializer:

```
provider :twitter, nil, nil, setup: true
```

routes.rb:

```
get '/settings/auth/:provider/setup' => 'settings/authorization_callbacks#setup'
```

This is the setup action

```
def setup
  application_id = params[:application_id].present? ? params[:application_id] : request.env["rack.session"]["omniauth.params"]["application_id"]
  application = Application.find(application_id)
  request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_id] = application.identifier
  request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_secret] = application.secret
  render :text => "Setup complete.", :status => 404
end
```

Result is 400 Bad Request and I have no idea why...
I checked and the right application is called, setting the right values in the "omniauth.strategy".

Maybe someone who already implemented this can guess what's the problem with my code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in omniauth-twitter gem.

The keys to set for Twitter are

```
request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:consumer_key] = application.identifier
request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:consumer_secret] = application.secret
```

https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter/issues/100